# Python - xml.etree.ElementTree - How to get root attributes name

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get root attributes but I get empy dict.
My file, an xbrl Italian balance sheet file, has these first lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<**xbrl** **xmlns**="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" **xmlns:itcc-ci-ese**="http://www.infocamere.it/itnn/fr/itcc/ci/ese/2018-11-04" **xmlns:link**="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" **xmlns:itcc-ci**="http://www.infocamere.it/itnn/fr/itcc/ci/2018-11-04" **xmlns:iso4217**="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" **xmlns:xlink**="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" **xmlns:xbrli**="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"> 
... ... .... ....
<**/xbrl**>
```

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('...\\000001108.XBRL')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.attrib)
```

Output:

```
{}
```

I was expecting:

```
{xmlns: .., xmlns:itcc-ci-ese .., xmlns:link: .., xmlns:itcc-ci: ..., xmlns:iso4217: ..., xmlns:xlink: ..., xmlns:xbrli: ...}
```

Comment: Those asterik characters * around the element names and the attribute names look strange to me. I think it is not valid to start the name with an * character according to XML specs (see also https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags ). 

So the parser might not be able to parse the XML, resulting in an empty tree.